# MS Access Query - How To Return 0?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm a beginner here, I'm trying to create a query to count the feedback outstanding for a given team team leader. When there is feedback outstanding the below returns the number of items.

When there isn't any feedback the query doesn't return anything. I need it to return 0. How can I make this work please?

The code of the rest of the query is below:

```
SELECT Count(Feedback.ID) AS CountOfID, UserIDAgentsTLsLocations.TeamLeader, Feedback.Fedback
FROM UserIDAgentsTLsLocations INNER JOIN Feedback ON UserIDAgentsTLsLocations.UserID = Feedback.AgentUsername
GROUP BY UserIDAgentsTLsLocations.TeamLeader, Feedback.Fedback
HAVING (((UserIDAgentsTLsLocations.TeamLeader)="DG") AND ((Feedback.Fedback)=False));
```

I'm using MS Access 2010 if that helps.

Any suggestions you can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `Left Join` to get the count as zero even there is no feedback

```
SELECT Count(Feedback.ID) AS CountOfID,
       UserIDAgentsTLsLocations.TeamLeader,
       Feedback.Fedback
FROM   UserIDAgentsTLsLocations
       LEFT JOIN Feedback
               ON UserIDAgentsTLsLocations.UserID = Feedback.AgentUsername
               AND Feedback.Fedback = False 
Where  UserIDAgentsTLsLocations.TeamLeader = 'DG' 
GROUP  BY UserIDAgentsTLsLocations.TeamLeader,
          Feedback.Fedback
```

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for this, I get an error saying "No current record", how do I make it create a row and show 0? Sorry

Comment: Do you have `TeamLeader = 'DG'`  in `UserIDAgentsTLsLocations` table ?

Comment: Yes, he appears in the UserIDAgentsTLsLocations table

Comment: Apologies, he's listed as David Green in the field rather than DG, his initials are used in a completely unrelated table. I've tried changing Where  UserIDAgentsTLsLocations.TeamLeader = 'DG' to Where  UserIDAgentsTLsLocations.TeamLeader = 'David Green' but it returns the same error